# Способы аутентификации в Django REST Framework

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

Здравствуйте.

Не могу найти, каким образом в `DRF` можно авторизоваться при помощи `login` и `token` ?

Я не очень хорошо понимаю смысл широко распространённого `TokenAuthentication`, особенно когда я запросы шлю с клиента, ведь `login` и `password` пользователя доступны из `js` кода.

В [django-tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), есть такой способ авторизации, но сам `tastypie` не подходит по ряду причин.

Comment: А что не получается из фирменного руководства? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал немного специфически, но мне такая реализация по душе:

Так генерю токен:

```
import string, random

def token_generator(size=100, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
```

Так делаю криптографический ключ, на основе этого токена:

```
def encode_user_token(self):
    data = {
        "token": self.token,
    }

    token = signing.dumps(
        json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':')), compress=True)

    return token
```

Метод модели, для генерации нового ключа:

```
def generate_token(self):
    self.token = token_generator()
    self.save()
```

Так проверяю ключ на соответствие:

```
def decode_token(user_token):
    token = None
    try:
        token = signing.loads(
            user_token)#, max_age=300)
    except SignatureExpired:
        logger.exception("token expired")
        print('token expired')
    except BadSignature:
        logger.exception("token invalid")
        print('token invalid')
    if token:
        token = json.loads(token)
        return token['token']
```

Так сделал Authentication backend:

```
from rest_framework import authentication
from rest_framework import exceptions

class CryptographicAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        token = request.GET.get('token')

        if not token:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such token')       

        try:
            token = decode_token(token)
            user = User.objects.get(token=token)
        except:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Authentication Failed')

        #user.generate_token()
        return (user, None)
```

Так же сделал такой сигнал:

```
from django.dispatch import Signal


token_data = Signal(providing_args=["token_data"])
```

И такой ресивер:

```
@receiver(token_data)
def example_receiver(**kwargs):
    token_data = kwargs['token_data']
```

Возможно покажется решение нагромождённым и глупым, но я получил что хотел, а главное - опыт.